# TCP - How to Close Client created inside thread -C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, client, terminate

I have a question 
.
I have many threads .. inside each thread a client is created 
I want to terminate a thread in a way that it destructs the client created inside it 
How ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think you do. I think you want to close the client socket primarily, and have that cause the thread to exit.

Answer (score 1):

If the client thread is blocked in `recv()` or `read()`, just shutdown the socket for input. That will cause the read/receive method to return zero, indicating end of stream, which should cause any correctly written handling code to close the socket and exit.